# How were the Vega balloons deployed?

Tags: venus, balloons

The [Vega mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vega_program#Balloon) included balloon deployment into Venus' atmosphere. Deploying weather balloons on Earth is  easy, but i imagine it is quite complicated in other planets' atmosphere  from a spaceship.

- how were these balloons packed into the Vega spaceship ?
- how were those balloons  inserted into Venus atmosphere? (reentry vehicle dropping it?)
- how were those balloons inflated ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In English - http://mentallandscape.com/V_Vega.htm

> The aerostat was stowed in a toroidal compartment fastened to the cap section of the spherical reentry vehicle, fitting around the lander's helical antenna. This included spherical bottles of compressed helium, and a 35 square-meter parachute used during the filling of the balloon. Deployment, diagrammed above, had to be planned carefully and controlled by barometric sensors. If the balloon was filled too early or too quickly, it would burst in the low pressure of high altitudes. If it was filled to slowly, the assembly would drift too far down and be destroyed by high temperatures.

[image]

Comment: Impressive piece of engineering